# Correct way to calibrate SDR RX into a measuring receiver

Tags: power, rf, receiver, input-impedance, sdr

While playing with my SDR (Software Defined Radio) Board, I was interested in performing a TX output power table at different center frequencies and TX antenna gains.

However, unfortunately, I do not have a spectrum analyzer for direct TX power measurements, but I do have an RF frequency generator. Therefore, my intentions are to generate signals with well known RF power and measure them with the RX of the SDR, somehow converting it into a calibrated measuring receiver. From this, I would just repeat the setup but now with a direct TX-RX connection. This way, I would know what power I'm transmitting with TX as well.

The problem is that I'm not really sure what should be the quantities that I measure in RX in order to make it into a measuring receiver and I don't know what the digital words measured in RX correspond to voltage neither. Also, I have to assume that RX does not have a 50 ohm impedance neither does TX. Therefore, I can't just convert the power from the 50 ohm frequency generator into Vpk and then use this result to calculate the digital Vpk of the IQ data in RX, since there would be a reflection in the wave and the result would be wrong... right? Or is there a way to measure the impedance of the RX (and then of the TX)?

Can someone please clarify me the methods? I'm not familiar with RF at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This method (calibrating with a known source of power) is exactly how many university projects use USRPs.

Comment: Since you have a VNA: it's quite a bit fairer to measure the RX impedance directly than it is to measure TX impedance. Do it while receiving, so that everything is in its working state. Also, do a calculation of the error (in dB!) you're doing with say a 50Ω vs (60+j10)Ω mismatch. Maybe that error is within acceptable bounds.

Comment: Still, I don't know how to proceed from that measurement. Imagining I got a measurement of the RX impedance, I'm still not familiar with the protocol on how to calibrate RX then. Do I then calculate the reflectance coefficient between the frequency source and RX and convert the IQ words of RX into voltage? Or should my measurements be done in the frequency domain?

Comment: Spectrum Analyzers are calibrated against RF power meters, usually in an arrangement where a single power splitter delivers to both the meter and the analyzer without any more cables in between, and the RF connectors closed with a torque wrench, to get the differences in signal path down to the absolute minimum.

Comment: I understand all those comments, but still my initial question is still unanswered. Even thought I appreciate your knowledge on the setup that should be used, my question relates to what digital signal processing techniques should I be using in order to obtain a calibrated measuring receiver that could then calibrate a transmitter. Should I get the DFT of the results and analyze the peak amplitude? should I perform the Vrms of the digital IQ data time series? I have no idea, since impedances and ADC ref voltage are not known.

Comment: why the dft? That will give you nothing new, thanks to parseval's theorem, power or energy in time is proportional to power or energy in frequency domain. And power is simply the magnitude square of your samples .

Comment: So, if I understood your teaching correctly, the procedure should be:
1) Measure RX impedance (while receiving);
2) Compute the reflection coefficient  R between the RX and a 50 ohm frequency generator (FG);
3) Configure the FG to output a known power (hence a known Vpk) and receive the IQ samples coming from the frequency generator;
4) Through the magnitude of R, compute the actual power received and also the actual Vpk received;
5) Infer the IQ word <-> V relation from the actual Vpk previously computed;
...

Comment: Now from this step is where my questions start. First, please confirm me that steps 1-5 are indeed correct. Second, I am really interested in the power received at the output frequency of the FG. Therefore, I think my measurement in the time domain i going to introduce noise, is it not? 

From this, I thought about doing the following:
6) Compute the Vrms of the IQ data received in the time domain: Vrms = Vpeak/sqrt(2), and Vpeak = max[sqrt(I² + Q²)];

And now? Can I already connect TX to RX (but what is the TX impedance if it is not fair to measure it in VNA?)